# What happened to DeserializeXNode?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I've got the following in my Windows Phone 8.1 **Silverlight** application

```
var xdocObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(fileContents, "utyRoot__");
retVal.Title = xdocObject.Descendants("title").Single().Value;
```

However when I go from Json.Net 6.0.6 to 6.0.8, I am met with an API that no longer has the `DeserializeXNode` method on it. I can't find anything on Json.Net's website as to what happened to this. Even in the source code it still appears to exist. Leads me to believe it's a botched build that got pushed to NuGet.

Any insight/advice here?

Comment: Are you using the correct DLL for your platform?  The `(De)SerializeXNode` methods are not available for the .Net 2.0 library and the portable 4.0 library, according to the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs) (see line 1052).

Comment: Since I didn't do anything but a `nuget update` on the package, I'm at the mercy of the package creator. This is my attempt to point out a bug in this process (if there is one) or try and find an alternative for this code.